# Не отображает метод доставки Shiptor и выдает ошибку

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, методы

Всем привет!
После установки плагина доставки Шиптор, постоянно выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методов доставки не видно ни в админке, ни на сайте. Как их сделать видимыми? Спасибо!

Comment: Пишите автору плагина

Comment: И скажите ему, что его код давно устарел: " Плагин устанавливался и тестировался на WordPress 5.3.0 и WooСommerce версия 3.8.1": https://shiptor.ru/integration/modules/woo