# Проблема с плагином Wordpress Shiptor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я не первый с таким вопросом
[Не отображает метод доставки Shiptor и выдает ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157264/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-shiptor-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1157264/398802

Comment: Не нужно создавать дубликаты вопросов)